# Sanitize GET data through PHP constructor

Tags: php, constructor

I have the following constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
    foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
        $_GET[$key] = addslashes($value);
    }
    $this->get = $_GET;
}
```

and it's used like so:

```
$app->get['id']
```

Where 'id' is the parameter being passed through the URL.
Is there a good way to sanitize all the data through the constructor?

Comment: Different languages/contexts have different special characters and thus require different treatments. I don’t think it’s a good idea to send all data through the same function.

Comment: probably not a good idea, but if you did, I would pass the $_GET explicitly as a parameter.  Better not to use global data inside your class.

Comment: Have to agree with @Gumbo - there's no 'one size fits all' approach to data sanitation.

Comment: I agree, but I am working on already developed code... just trying to fix what I was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly shorter way to do this:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->get = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this? To prevent SQL injection?

Preventing injection should be done at the query-building level, and should most definitely be done with a more relevant function like `mysql_real_escape_string`, which will catch all odd cases, not just quotes. What you are doing here is no better than the infamous magic quotes functionality that has since been removed from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of variable you're expecting you could cast it to the desired type such as

```
$this->id = (int)$app->get['id']; //forces type to be integer
```